# Add folder icon in the document library webpart view

Tags: list-view

Hello Sharepoint Folks,

I have a page where one of the webparts is a document library. I used to see a folder icon or document type icon until I changed the view, and the folder icon stopped showing.

Below is the current view. 2013 - 2018 is a folder and I want to show the folder icon before it. I kept playing with different views but nothing worked for me.

[image: Document Library Webpart]

[image: Sample site with folder icon]

Can you please advise what I am missing here? What should be the view I use?

Answer (score 1):

Select Type (icon linked to document) column while modifying the view.